# Download web page only if it has been modified

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I'm building and app for an assessment and I need to download a web page only if it has been modified since the last time I downloaded it. I need to store the date of last change as an Long, so the method getDate() returns a long.
I tried to use HttpURLConnection and URLConnection, but I couldn't manage to achieve a solution.
Within my attempts I tried to use:

- [If-Modified-Since](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25), but, somehow, I didn't receive the 304 response code, only the 200. The code:

  ```
  HttpURLConnection huc = null;
  try {
      URL url = new URL(pages.get(0).getUrl());
      huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      huc.setIfModifiedSince(pages.get(0).getDate());
      huc.connect();
      Log.d("App", "Since: " + huc.getIfModifiedSince());
      Log.d("App", "Response: " + huc.getResponseCode());
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
     //output
  since: 1354320000000 - which is the return of the getDate method.
  Response: 200
  ```
- [html etags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag), but I couldn't retrieve the information from the response, because the server doesn't answer the Last-Modified tag.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have control of the server or are you just hitting some random site on the internet? A server has to be configured to return 304 and use etags.

Comment: I don't have control of the server, but is there a way of doing this without downloading the hole web page and comparing it?

Comment: I used the size of the content to see if it has changed or not.. huc.getContentLength(); - huc is a HttpURLConnection.